# Unable to remove user named "Administrator" on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, user-account

I've created an administrator-level account called "Administrator" on my iMac (macOS Sierra).  I basically did this to ease copying existing user documents, etc. from a backup using the Migration Assistant without any name/user conflicts.

Now I've copied stuff over, I'd like to delete this account named "Administrator".  Using another administrator-level account, I login, but when I access the Users & Groups System Preferences, the user "Administrator" doesn't appear in the list of current or other users.  Therefore, I can't delete it.  Any ideas as to why this user doesn't show up in the list?

Comment: Is the account you're logged into an account with administrative privileges? Make sure you're an administrator

Comment: How and when (in the set up process) did you create the admin account "Administrator"?

Comment: @NoahL - yes, I'm logged in as another admin-level user when I try to delete "Administrator.

Comment: @klanomath I created this account during the initial machine setup phase (macOS Sierra post-install "wizard")

Comment: Try doing it from terminal: http://www.kombitz.com/2013/11/07/how-to-delete-a-local-user-using-command-line-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Please add the output of `dscl . -read /Users/administrator`. Please omit any binary data (e.g. jpeg icon) and sha1 data

Comment: Thanks all. I was able to delete it from the terminal per @NoahL